# Order book trading / low volume

Tags: trading, stock-analysis, international-trading, trading-volume

In a stock exchange where there is low volume overall , can a trading strategy based on the order book be effective ?
Given that you have all the executions and the best five bids and asks.
Any recommendations for a book on this subject

Answer (score 2):

I would not be trading anything with low volume. You will find it hard to get the price you want to buy and to sell. There would usually be large price gaps and it is a sure way to lose money on every trade.

You are better off trading instruments with as high volume as possible - better chance of buying and selling at price you want and less change of price gaps.

Comment: You're totally right, but my question is , how effective can an order book based stategy be ,to anticipate trends or say for example accumulation by a big fund

Comment: Order books are continually changing - new orders coming in, orders being cancelled, and then there are hidden orders. So I wouldn't base my whole strategy on the order book, especially with illiquid stocks.

Comment: What do you suggest ?

Comment: Suggestions for what? A trading strategy? That could take a book to answer, there are many strategies. A quick one, wait for an inside bar after a low bar and enter a long trade the next day above the high of the inside bar.

Answer (score -3):

There is an edge in low liquidity instruments simply because the biggest, most skilled traders in the marketplace might avoid these due to lack of liquidity. For a retail trader with a small account, the price movement is easier to read as the rate of price change is low.
Many traders are only focusing on low liquidity instruments and do very well trading these while knowing they cannot compound their account significantly.

Comment: Are you making lots of money in these, because I have only heard of people lossing money - simply because of the large gaps in price and not being able tovget the price they want when trying to sell, that if they are able to sell at all.

Comment: I don't trade using these methods as I don't look at the order book at all. But I do focus on edges that are size constrained, areas which big funds would overlook. The most liquid instruments are also the most competitive because the biggest funds with the best traders will focus on them.

Comment: There is no edge with low volumes at all. If you are looking to buy something you want volume in the opposite direction so you can get the price you want. The same when you are selling. If there is no volume you won't  be able to buy or sell at the price you are after. I want to trade the most competitive instruments I can  with the biggest funds with the biggest traders, because then I can easily buy and sell and not move the market with my tinny order.

Comment: You're missing the obvious. A trader that trades big size in a small market can push the price to the direction he needs it to go. As I said, the biggest markets also attract the smartest players and in trading, you never want to go head to head with the best, there is no profit in that.

Comment: No you are missing the point - there is no money to be made in illiquid stocks. If you trade big size in a small market you will push up the price before you have fully buy your order so you would end up buying at a higher price than you wanted, and then you will push the price down when trying to sell getting a much lower price than you wanted. If you have a tested and proven trading system you don't care who you trade against all you should care about is if there is liquidity in the opposite direction so you can get the price you want without moving the market.

Comment: If your concern is about moving the market then you are in the wrong game, because you will be in a lossing game. If you are moving the market with your order then you are buying at a higher price than necessary and selling at a lower price than necessary - you are lossing buying in and lossing selling out. Good luck with that.

Comment: All orders move the market, the question is only how much. If small orders wouldn't move the market, there would be no fluctuations. You fail to see strategies which fall outside of the norm. If there is no benefit to trading low liquidity instruments, who are these fools trading them? Why are many funds focusing on lower liquidity instruments instead of them all trading SP?

Comment: @misantroop can you tell us more about how your friends trade illiquide instruments (low volume) , what strategy do they use ? I want to learn about different trading styles

Comment: Obviously they do not give me any details but the idea seems to be that you have more influence over the price and on that information you can build strategies. Also, since there are few players involved, you can read what they do more easily because it's difficult to hide intention in illiquid instruments.

Comment: @misantroop thank you for your answer , i'll keep searching

Comment: @halim - he cannot give you any strategy because there are none. If you want to buy an illiquid stock that last traded at $1.00, whose current highest bid price is at $1.00 and current lowest ask price is at $1.20, you will need to place a bid price of $1.20 to buy it - thus you have just moved the price up 20%. You now have to wait for the bid price to move up by 20% just to break even. This is why the smart money does not touch illiquid stocks. The only thing you will do with them is lose money. You can read any book about trading, they will all tell you to stay away from illiquide stocks.

Comment: @Victor thank you for your answer . But i have to say that i'm forced to trade in a low/mid volume-manipulated market and all i want, is to understand the mouvement of the "smart" money in this market, given that i have the executions ect ...

Comment: @halim - why are you forced to trade low volume markets? No one is forcing you to do anything. As I said there is no smart money in low liquidity markets, that is why they are low liquidity - because no one in their right mind would trade them - only dummies who think they have an edge because they are the only one trading them, and it makes them feel good that with their small orders they can move the market - but all that will happen in the end is they will lose money. I don't know how many times I have to warn you.

Comment: @Victor It's for a project , i'm just gathering knowledge